# iOS deployment: Errors when trying to Archive

Tags: ios, deployment

I'm trying to build my app for iOS and the more I go further, the more errors I get. I spent hours dealing with them, and I need your help with some issues. I have all certificates needed.

When trying to Archive my app, I ge the following errors:

```
Check dependencies

Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.
No profiles for 'net.package.my' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'net.package.my'.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'
```

1. There are no devices registered in my account developer website? Huh? I don't have an iPhone, I bought mac for the develoyment process, why do I get this error and how I can overpass it?
2. No profiles for my package - why? what does it checks exactly? I followed every single step of the deployment proccess..
3. Code signing is required.. ok where?

My settings for signing:

[image]
If I pick my profile I get error about conflict, and that I should change the settings to iOS developer.